# link image to one SPECIFIC page in Word 16 mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, images

I'm searching for days to find a solution to my problem without any result. 
I'm editing a publication where I would like to have text on the left page and images on the right (in the final binding). So I tried all the tricks with anchoring wrapping, floating text boxes etc. but I did not manage to fix an image to one specific page. As an example- page 5 is text and I'd like to have images on page 6. I arrange the pictures on page 6 but as soon as I continue to write on page 5 and reach the end, my pictures start to jump to page 7. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a wrapping attribute on the images, instead use the Inline with Text option. Images with wrapping text (also Text Boxes by default) are anchored to paragraphs. When you add new paragraphs of text above the anchoring paragraph, this will cause your images to move.

If there is a layout design reason why these images also need other text surrounding them on the Even numbered page, then consider placing the images in a table with the borders not visible. The table should not be floating and neither should the images in the table, but you can make it look like the image is floating by placing text in surrounding table cells.

[image]